# What prevents someone from tainting the coin tumbling pool of the Wasabi wallet?

Tags: coinbase.com, mixing, taint-analysis, wasabi-wallet

Wasabi is a new type of wallet with a built in tumbler if I'm correct. What stops someone from tainting the tumbling pool of coins with non-approved coins? I'm weary of using these privacy tools as I don't want my coinbase account frozen just because someone mixed a bad coin in the lot.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody prevents it. Tumbling however reduces the chances of getting taunted by increasing the BTC pool's size.

If you have problems with this method of coins mixing for any reason just don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Coinbase looks for a five hops before / after incoming / outgoing TX. So adding extra hops will be enough for now. It can be automated with [Samourai Wallet's Ricochet](https://samouraiwallet.com/features/ricochet) or [my scripts for bitcoin-qt](https://github.com/kristapsk/bitcoin-scripts).

Comment: If everyone knows that coinbase analyzes 5 hops. Why can't they just detect this 5 hop pattern to see all the people using the samourai wallet?

Comment: Samourai Wallet's ricochet send is detectable, as it sends some small amount of BTC to Samourai Wallet's donation address. But there are other ways to do multi-hop send on blockchain too, as I mentioned.

Most important thing - it is asymmetric attack on blockchain analysis. Sender's costs are relatively little, but analysis to fight this needs to increase number of hops they analyze, and do that for all transactions, not single one.